# How to get height when setting layout_weight attribute in LinearLayout

Tags: android

> I want to use self-define view,but i donot know how to get height.

and concrete code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/timer_layout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <com.zzb.resume.views.DotView
        android:id="@+id/timer_line1"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/timer_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/timer_line1"
        android:src="@mipmap/time2"/>
    <com.zzb.resume.views.DotView
        android:id="@+id/timer_line2"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> In DotView i get height=0, and how i can get height when layout_weight="1".

Answer (score 0):

cause your imageview and dotView cover all the layout.You just need to add weight_sum to your layout .[http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum](http://weight_sum)

> You shouldn't use dp to set your size because it won't be absolute.
>   Best way to do that set it changing weight_sum-layout_weight rate.

now you have weight_sum 3
if one of your view has layout_weight=1 it means that it will cover %33 of layout.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/timer_layout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weight_sum=3;
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.zzb.resume.views.DotView
            android:id="@+id/timer_line1"
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="0"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/timer_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_below="@id/timer_line1"
            android:src="@mipmap/time2"/>
        <com.zzb.resume.views.DotView
            android:id="@+id/timer_line2"
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```